# how to Load scss dynamically in Angular 6 based on customers in single angular application?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have an application used by multiple customers, each of which require their own unique theme/color scheme loaded at run time. How can i load scss file based on customer in angular 6?

Comment: you can have a global styles and switch it on load based on the condition

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please provide me example @Aravind

Comment: did you get a chance to see the material.angular.io and change the themes and play across

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simples solution is using simple css for this issue, or you may be obligated to manage file conversion to find the correct one to use for the user.

You can simply print a `<link>` tag putting a different value in the `href` attribute. For example yellow user logs in, and with the authentication token you send in the response user's personal css url, for example a respose like this:

```
{
  x-auth-token: 'asjdjsajdsajsadjsadjsasadj',
  css-href: 'path/user.css'
}
```

Into your service you can put `css-href` into a variable, like `userCssHref`

Then in your template, possibly into `index.html`, you can print something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ userCssHref }}">
```

Obviously you must find a way to access that variable